# Automatically suggest to install the needed framework version if is not installed?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, .net-framework-version

Suppose that I will target my `Winforms` application to Framework 4.5, but the user machine only has the Framework 3.X, and the user attempts to run the application, then the application will not run because the needed framework version is not installed on the machine...

...but there is a way to perform from my app an smart preventive operation in that case? (instead of let windows OS to display a non-friendly error msgbox)

What I want to do is for example show a msgbox to recommend the user to download X framework package in X url to be able to run the app, only if the required framework is not installed on the machine.

Answer (score 4):

If you distribute your application using [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh45kb66%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) you will get exactly this (among really other cool features as automatic updates).

Comment: my app is a windows form project, sorry to have confused you

Comment: ClickOnce works perfectly with WinForms, check this for more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh45kb66(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @pitoloko that's exactly what it should be to use ClickOnce deployment. Looks like you are on your lucky day. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh45kb66(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Could you give more information about that? like an example adapted to my question maybe please?, really I could not understand how the clickonce could be the solution for me. I've thinked that the clickonce was only for other kind of projects (I see that i were wrong) but anyways, this feature is not to publish applications over internet? (that's not my intention). I've tried to read a step-by-step first ClickOnce for newbies but when I try to "publish" the application it just creates an (irrelevant?) setup.exe with some other strange files. this will not work for portable apps?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this by changing the setting under prerequisite of the Setup project.

1. Right click the setup project and go to `properties`
2. Select `Prerequisite` button
3. It will open up another pop up window at the button of the window you will see three radio button options.
4. Select `Download the prerequisite from the component vendor's web site`

When the target machine doesn't have the .net frame work instead of error message it will display download link to download .net framework.

[image]